# finding the error on an online course exercise

Tags: python

I just began to learn python from an online course and this is one of the examples that they posted on their page.

Fix the error

```
def make_greeting(name, greeting = "Hello"):
    return (greeting + " " + name + "!")

# get name and greeting, send to make_greeting 
print(make_greeting(get_name(), get_greeting()))

def get_name():
    name_entry = input("enter a name: ")
    return name_entry

def get_greeting():
    greeting_entry = input("enter a greeting: ")
    return greeting_entry
```

Comment: Python has pretty good Error Traceback . Maybe you could try to read the error message thoroughly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def make_greeting(name, greeting = "Hello"): 
     return (greeting + " " + name + "!")

# get name and greeting, send to make_greeting

def get_name(): 
    name_entry = input("enter a name: ") 
    return name_entry

def get_greeting(): 
    greeting_entry = input("enter a greeting: ") 
    return greeting_entry

print(make_greeting(get_name(), get_greeting()))
```

Comment: u have to define the funcnion before its call.